# What has to be the condition of $x(n)$ so that the sum $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n+1}x(k)$ is convergent/divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If anyone could give a quick hint to the problem as stated in the title, that would be very appreciated.

EDT. I mean, if $x>0$ or $x<0$ for all $n$ then it would be divergent, right?

Comment: Why not rewrite as $\sum_{k=-n-1}^\infty x(-k)$? And, the conditions for this summation converging are basically the same as those for essentially any other series.

Comment: Is $x(k)$  a function $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @DonThousand thanks! Got it!